# Get items count and items size of a particular account under hold in G-Suit

Tags: google-vault-api

I am G-Suit admin user having google vault privileges. I am trying to get items count and items size of a particular account placed under hold. Could you please suggest an API endpoint to retrieve items count and items size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create an export. Once the export is created you can get its starts without having to download it. The export that you created will generate stats about what information is holding.

Other than that your option is to actually download everything and do your own statistics.

### References

- [matter.exports ExportStats (Google Vault API reference)](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports#exportstats)
- [matters.exports.create (Google Vault API reference)](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports/create)